# How to append columns horizontally in R in a loop?

Tags: r

I want to create a matrix of stockdata from n number of companies from a ticker list, though im struggling with appending them horizontally, it only works to append them vertically.
Also other functions like merge or rbind which i have tried, but they cannot work with the variables parsed as a string, so the hard part here is that i want to append n variables which are retrieved from the tickerlist which has n number of stocks. Other suggestions are welcome to get the same result.
Stocklist data:

```
> dput(stockslist)
structure(list(V1 = c("AMD", "MSFT", "SBUX", "IBM", "AAPL", "GSPC", 
"AMZN")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library(plyr)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(plotly)

tickerlist <- "sp500.csv"  #CSV containing tickers on rows
stockslist <- read.csv("sp500.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = F)
nrstocks = length(stockslist[,1]) #The number of stocks to download
maxretryattempts <- 5 #If there is an error downloading a price how many 
times to retry
startDate = as.Date("2010-01-13")

for (i in 1:nrstocks) {
  stockdata <- getSymbols(c(stockslist[i,1]), src = "yahoo", from = 
startDate)
  # pick 6th column of the ith stock
  write.table((eval(parse(text=paste(stockslist[i,1]))))[,6], file = 
"test.csv", append = TRUE, row.names=F)

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do `eval(parse(...))` in your loop. Can you show a sample of `stockslist` so we can better understand your structure? Your code does not indicate where you want to append rows/columns. Can you make this question [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a sample of your data (as already requested) and an idea of what your output would look like?

Comment: I cannot upload a file here, but it is just these tickers, one on each row saved as the sp500.csv AMD
MSFT
SBUX
IBM
AAPL
GSPC
AMZN

Comment: You don't have to upload a file (in fact, I discourage it, typically unnecessary). If you read the link in my previous comment, there are suggestions for providing sample data through the use of `dput` or `read.table(text = ...)`; both work well.

Comment: Further, you talk about "appending" but nothing in your code suggests you do anything other than download data and save to CSV. Other than the really-confusing `eval(parse(...))` part of your code, there doesn't appear to be a glaring problem with what you've provided. I wonder if this would be a good example (at some point) for suggesting [lists of dataframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207), a more elegant way to load and process multiple data.frames/matrices. Once in a list, `rbind` works great.

Comment: CSVs are linear, left to right, top to bottom, so you cannot accrete additional columns by writing to the same file multiple times (except maybe in the special case of a one-row table..?). Make a big table in R first with `cbind` and then call write.table once.

Comment: The eval(parse(...)) is to input the stocklists as strings, else the list will simply use the text AMD, MSFT etc, when i use the eval(parse(...)) it uses the variables created by getsymbols.
the problem of cbind is that my number of lists is unknown, i want to simply input a list of like around 1000 tickers so it first creates 1000 df's.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly a great opportunity to talk about [lists of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207). Having said that ...

Side bar: I really don't like side-effects. `getSymbols` defaults to using side-effect to saving the data into the parent frame/environment, and though this may be fine for most uses, I prefer functional methods. Luckily, using `auto.assign=FALSE` returns its behavior to within my bounds of comfort.

```
library(quantmod)
stocklist <- c("AMD", "MSFT")
startDate <- as.Date("2010-01-13")

dat <- sapply(stocklist, getSymbols, src = "google", from = startDate, auto.assign = FALSE,
              simplify = FALSE)
str(dat)
# List of 2
#  $ AMD :An 'xts' object on 2010-01-13/2017-05-16 containing:
#   Data: num [1:1846, 1:5] 8.71 9.18 9.13 8.84 8.98 9.01 8.55 8.01 8.03 8.03 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr [1:5] "AMD.Open" "AMD.High" "AMD.Low" "AMD.Close" ...
#   Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
#   xts Attributes:  
# List of 2
#   ..$ src    : chr "google"
#   ..$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-05-16 21:01:37"
#  $ MSFT:An 'xts' object on 2010-01-13/2017-05-16 containing:
#   Data: num [1:1847, 1:5] 30.3 30.3 31.1 30.8 30.8 ...
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#   ..$ : NULL
#   ..$ : chr [1:5] "MSFT.Open" "MSFT.High" "MSFT.Low" "MSFT.Close" ...
#   Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
#   xts Attributes:  
# List of 2
#   ..$ src    : chr "google"
#   ..$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-05-16 21:01:37"
```

Though I only did two symbols, it should work for many more without problem. Also, I shifted to using Google since Yahoo was asking for authentication.

You used `write.csv(...)`, realize that you will lose the timestamp for each datum, since the CSV will look something like:

```
"AMD.Open","AMD.High","AMD.Low","AMD.Close","AMD.Volume"
8.71,9.2,8.55,9.15,32741845
9.18,9.26,8.92,9,22658744
9.13,9.19,8.8,8.84,34344763
8.84,9.21,8.84,9.01,24875646
```

Using "AMD" as an example, consider:

```
write.csv(as.data.frame(AMD), file="AMD.csv", row.names = TRUE)
head(read.csv("~/Downloads/AMD.csv", row.names = 1))
#            AMD.Open AMD.High AMD.Low AMD.Close AMD.Volume
# 2010-01-13     8.71     9.20    8.55      9.15   32741845
# 2010-01-14     9.18     9.26    8.92      9.00   22658744
# 2010-01-15     9.13     9.19    8.80      8.84   34344763
# 2010-01-19     8.84     9.21    8.84      9.01   24875646
# 2010-01-20     8.98     9.00    8.76      8.87   22813520
# 2010-01-21     9.01     9.10    8.77      8.99   37888647
```

To save all of them at once:

```
ign <- mapply(function(x, fn) write.csv(as.data.frame(x), file = fn, row.names = TRUE),
              dat, names(dat))
```

There are other ways to store your data such as `Rdata` files (`save()`).

It is not clear to me if you are intending to append them as additional *columns* (i.e., `cbind` behavior) or as rows (`rbind`). Between the two, I tend towards "rows", but I'll start with "columns" first.

### "Appending" by column

This may be appropriate if you want day-by-day ticker comparisons (though there are arguably better ways to prepare for this). You'll run into problems, since they have (and most likely will have) different numbers of rows:

```
sapply(dat, nrow)
#  AMD MSFT 
# 1846 1847
```

In this case, you might want to join based on the dates (row names). To do this well, you should probably convert the row names (dates) to a column and `merge` on that column:

```
dat2 <- lapply(dat, function(x) {
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  x$date <- rownames(x)
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x
})
datwide <- Reduce(function(a, b) merge(a, b, by = "date", all = TRUE), dat2)
```

As a simple demonstration, remembering that there is one more row in "MSFT" than in "AMD", we can find that row and prove that things are still looking alright with:

```
which(! complete.cases(datwide))
# [1] 1251
datwide[1251 + -2:2,]
#            date AMD.Open AMD.High AMD.Low AMD.Close AMD.Volume MSFT.Open MSFT.High MSFT.Low MSFT.Close MSFT.Volume
# 1249 2014-12-30     2.64     2.70    2.63      2.63    7783709     47.44     47.62    46.84      47.02    16384692
# 1250 2014-12-31     2.64     2.70    2.64      2.67   11177917     46.73     47.44    46.45      46.45    21552450
# 1251 2015-01-02       NA       NA      NA        NA         NA     46.66     47.42    46.54      46.76    27913852
# 1252 2015-01-05     2.67     2.70    2.64      2.66    8878176     46.37     46.73    46.25      46.32    39673865
# 1253 2015-01-06     2.65     2.66    2.55      2.63   13916645     46.38     46.75    45.54      45.65    36447854
```

### "Appending" by row

`getSymbols` names the columns unique to the ticker, a slight frustration. Additionally, since we'll be discarding the column names, we should preserve the symbol name in the data.

```
dat3 <- lapply(dat, function(x) {
  ticker <- gsub("\\..*", "", colnames(x)[1])
  colnames(x) <- gsub(".*\\.", "", colnames(x))
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  x$date <- rownames(x)
  x$symbol <- ticker
  rownames(x) <- NULL
  x
}) # can also be accomplished with mapply(..., dat, names(dat))
datlong <- Reduce(function(a, b) rbind(a, b, make.row.names = FALSE), dat3)

head(datlong)
#   Open High  Low Close   Volume       date symbol
# 1 8.71 9.20 8.55  9.15 32741845 2010-01-13    AMD
# 2 9.18 9.26 8.92  9.00 22658744 2010-01-14    AMD
# 3 9.13 9.19 8.80  8.84 34344763 2010-01-15    AMD
# 4 8.84 9.21 8.84  9.01 24875646 2010-01-19    AMD
# 5 8.98 9.00 8.76  8.87 22813520 2010-01-20    AMD
# 6 9.01 9.10 8.77  8.99 37888647 2010-01-21    AMD
nrow(datlong)
# [1] 3693
```